# gem install json --platform=ruby failed windows 7 64 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, devkit

I'm following the DevKit to get json gem to install. However it has not worked for me. This has been preventing me to do `bundle install`. Computer is Win 7 64 bit. Commands for `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install` passed.

```
ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x64-mingw32]
Rails 4.2.6
```

Error

```
>gem install json --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/
generator
C:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160413-5616-jod3h4.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 f
or inspection.
Results logged to C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0/json-
1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check are you getting the proper ruby version in the file after doing *ruby dk.rb init*, if not specify the proper ruby version as in the program files, then try to run *ruby dk.rb install*, once this is done devkit is installed and you can install the required gem.

Comment: Wow. solved it with `gem install --verbose json -v 1.8.3`